# How do I join a Windows 8 PC into a domain?

Tags: networking, windows-8, windows-domain

How can I enroll a Windows 8 PC into an existing domain?

Comment: Does it not include `netdom`?  I have not tried it out myself yet.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. From the *Start* page, select *Control Panel*.
2. In the left sidebar, scroll all the way to the bottom and select *More settings*. Now you see the Control Panel much like it was in Windows 7.
3. Select *System and Security*, then *System*.
4. In the *Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings* section, select *Change settings*.
5. Do what you would have done in Windows 7.

Note: You must have Windows 8 Pro or Enterprise

Comment: I'm trying this. The domain field is grayed and not selectable.... any tips?

Comment: @Jason94 Any chance you've got Windows RT and not 8?  RT can't join a domain.  Also it appears only the Pro version of 8 can.

Comment: Quicker way: Right click in lower left hand corner, Click on system. Follow four and five above.

Comment: Damn Microsoft, why can't RT devices join a domain. Other than that downside they can be ideal for business users.

Comment: I think the RT limitation is because they want business users to use the Surface Pro, and not the cheaper Surface RT. Most desktop computers with W8 have Pro anyway.

Comment: RT was the worst decision by Microsoft, in the tablet sector...

Answer (score 1):

If you are not afraid of the command line, PowerShell offers an easy way to script / automate this through the [JoinDomainOrWorkgroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392154.aspx) WMI method:

```
# Acquire credentials for a domain account that has permission to join
$admin = Get-Credential

# these two variables are for convenience in shortening the command line
$user = $admin.UserName
$pw = $admin.GetNetworkCredential().Password

$CS = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem
$CS.JoinDomainOrWorkgroup("DOMAIN",$pw,$user,$null,3)
```

**Important Note:** you will need Windows 8 Pro or Enterprise to join a domain. The regular version of Windows 8 and Windows 8 RT are not able to join domains. You can see your version with the following PowerShell command:

```
(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
```

References:

- Win32_ComputerSystem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394102.aspx
- Win32_OperatingSystem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239.aspx
- JoinDomainOrWorkgroup: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392154.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to [use X-Setup](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/x_setup_pro.html) to join a 'non'-Pro Windows client to a domain. The software is out of date, but it was used for Windows XP Home Edition to do what you are asking.

I have not attempted it with Windows 8.

Comment: According to the X-Setup website, X-Setup is not compatible with Windows 8 and all operations regarding X-Setup have been shut down. As usual in a case like this, the X-Setup website doesn't offer any information about the possibility of running X-Setup in Windows 8 in compatibility mode.